# How to solve the error when dummy data gets stored in Django database with its id as none and all values as null

Tags: python, django, forms, web, error-handling

I had made this form in Django which takes some data and when a save button is clicked it saves it to the database. It stores the data that I give, but I noticed that every time I refreshed the page that contained the form it would automatically save an object with the Id as none and all values set to null. I wanted to know how to write a function that says the form only submits to the database when the save submit button is clicked and not when reloading the page and making a dummy object in the database.

Comment: You Should Show Some Code Also For Better Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is in the view, more specifically, how you're handling the request inside the view.
it seems that you're saving the object no matter what's the request method, that's why even refreshing the page will save a new object.

Comment: Oh, no the request method is POST basically I am saying request.POST.get = name of the input. Then and I assign name of the field with the models field and then say: name.save()

Comment: But all of this is happening only when that Save button is clicked. So i don't understand why it is saving a new object

Comment: can you show us the code ? so that we can better help you

Answer (score 0):

You must add csrf_token inside the form!

As in the example below ...

you write in file html

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="plan" id="id_plan" value="1">
<button>buy</button>
</form>
```

you write in models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(djangoUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User'))
```

you write in views.py

```
class testviews(TemplateView):
model: Account
    def forms_valid(self, form):
            user = Account.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            user.save()
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that but still is not working

Comment: Also, do you know how I can set all these forms to the current user. What I mean is I have used user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True); But when a object uploads to the database, I want it automatically to make it the current user who uploaded the object

Comment: You must set a request from views.py to each user

Comment: Did you get the result?

Comment: Not yet, once I do I will let you know. Thank you for your help